# How to get category image in magento 1.9 soap API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v1

```
$client     = new SoapClient('http://localhost/project/api/soap/?wsdl');

$user_name  = "username";
$password   = "password";

//$user_name  = $_POST["user_name"];
//$password   = $_POST["password"];

$response = array();
$session  = $client->login($user_name, $password);

//$result   = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.tree');
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category_attribute.list');

$response["Code"]     = "1";
$response["Message"]  = "suceess";
$response["categories"] = $result;

echo json_encode($response, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the API method `catalog_category.info`. Something like this added in your code should give you the needed information.

```
$categoryId = [YOUR CATEGORY_ID];
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.info', $categoryId);

$image = $result['image'];
```